# Using MessageEmbeds() in sqlite each() function

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a command that can be used to show all logs associated with a particular user. Logs are created by issuing a punishment and stored in a sqlite database (table cases).

My code (cleaned up) looks as follows:

```
let botembed = new MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(`Test`)
.setColor(`#3884FF`)
.setFooter(`Test`)
.setTimestamp();

let db = new sqlite.Database('./data/database.sqlite', sqlite.OPEN_READONLY);
db.each(`SELECT * from test`, (error, row) => {
    botembed.addField(`Test`, '${row.test_id}');
});

return message.channel.send(botembed);
```

What is returned, is an messageEmbed() with the author, color, footer and timestamp set, however no fields are added despite data being present in the database. I verified that the data is correctly requested (which it does, `console.log(row.test_id)` does return the expected values). I do not receive any error messages indicating what could be wrong.

I have tried to define the botembed within the db.each() statement resulting in similar returns. I have also tried to Google this issue, but it seems not too many have experienced this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I am unable to add new fields to my messageEmbed() this way?

Comment: To add to this: I figured out my return statement is executed before my ``db.each()`` function has started / completed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you try this and see if it works,

```js
let botembed = new MessageEmbed();

botembed.setAuthor(`Test`);
botembed.setColor(`#3884FF`);
botembed.setFooter(`Test`);
botembed.setTimestamp();

let db = new sqlite.Database('./data/database.sqlite', sqlite.OPEN_READONLY);
db.each(`SELECT * from test`, (error, row) => {
    botembed.addField(`Test`, '${row.test_id}');
});

return message.channel.send(botembed);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same result: The author, color, footer and timestamp are set correctly but fields still don't show up.